# Label widget wont move inside of frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm quite new to Tkinter but I have been practicing it for a bit now but whenever I try to move a label in a frame with grid geometry by specifying row and column, the label just stays in the middle.

In the code below, I try specifying the row and column for the name label which is in the top middle frame but it never moves. It just stays in the middle.

```
from tkinter import*

root=Tk()

frame_topleft = Frame(root, height=150, width=50, bg = "green")
frame_topmiddle = Frame(root, height=150, width=250, bg="red")
frame_topright = Frame(root, height=150, width=250, bg="green")
frame_bottomleft = Frame(root, height=300, width=50, bg="blue")
frame_bottommiddle = Frame(root, height=300, width=250, bg="yellow")
frame_bottomright = Frame(root, height=300, width=250, bg="blue")

label_name=Label(frame_topmiddle, text="Name", font="halvetica")
label_phone=Label(frame_topmiddle, text="Phone", font="halvetica")

frame_topmiddle.grid(row=0, column=1)
frame_topleft.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame_topright.grid(row=0, column=2)
frame_bottomleft.grid(row=1, column=0)
frame_bottommiddle.grid(row=1, column=1)
frame_bottomright.grid(row=1, column=2)

label_name.grid(row=0, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

So, I'm just wondering how I can fix this. I want the name label at the top left of the top middle frame.

Answer (score 0):

The `frame_topmiddle` shrinks to the size of `label_name` and is, by default, displayed at the center of (row 0, column 1).

If you set the `sticky` option of the grid method to 'nw':
`frame_topmiddle.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nw')`

then `frame_topmiddle` will be in the top left corner of (row 0, column 1) instead of the center.

If you want `frame_topmiddle` to keep its initial size, you need to do
`frame_topmiddle.grid_propagate(False)`.